# How to send the clientside OS active user details to server?

Tags: struts

I am working on a Struts (Version 1.3) based Application.

In my appication whenever a new record is created, an alert email is sent to the approvers who are configured in Database.

The alert email body contains the link (example `<a href="http://server:7778/DOD/login.jsp">` DOD ) for accessing the applicaiton.

Here, my requirement is when approver clicks on the link, if he is a valid approver, then i have to show the home page directly instead of the login page. but to show the home page i have to validate whether he is valid approver or not.

The approver just clicks on the link without giving his details. In the background i have to get his Operating System username and send to the server side JSP components.

How can i acheive this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the above requirement by adding the Encoded Approver User id as request parameter to the Application Link.  So when ever the request come from the Respective Approver, I will decode the user id request parameter and Verify that user id exist in the database. If it exists in the database then I will show the Home page otherwise I will display Unauthorized user access message.

Please ask me if any body not clear about the solution.